# can node-soap provide multiple services

Tags: node.js

I'm using the node-soap module created by milewise (and it seems great!). However, I have a requirement to provide multiple services based on different WSDLs. Is this possible with node-soap on the same sever:port? or do I need to combine the services into a single WSDL or perhaps run multiple services on separate node instances (I guess each on a separate port) and front that with a proxy?

Any ideas or assistance would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Sudipto

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can! Just create multiple service objects and register them with different XMLs (WSDLs) on different endpoint on the same server.

```
var xml1 = require('fs').readFileSync('myservice1.wsdl', 'utf8');
var xml2 = require('fs').readFileSync('myservice2.wsdl', 'utf8');

var server = ... // setup your server
var soap = require('soap');
soap.listen(server, '/wsdl1', myService1, xml1);
soap.listen(server, '/wsdl2', myService2, xml2);
```